# Discretized conserved values without necessarily using gauge symmetries

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, quantization

All of the examples I have seen for discrete conserved values (e.g. charge) invoke gauge symmetries, and thus extra degrees of freedom.  Is it possible to have a discretized/quantized conserved values in Lagrangian mechanics via global symmetry and, if it is possible, what does this necessarily say about the phase space and/or Lagrangian?

Comment: To clarify: When you list charge as an example of a discrete conserved quantity, are you referring to the condition that all charges are integer multiples of a fundamental amount of charge?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I would accept cases where the conserved quantity is not dense, which would include conserved quantities that are rational numbers.  integer multiples of some base value would be one possibility (a common one in QM, of course).